# How to learn the intuition behind probabilistic arguments in Algebraic Complexity lower bounds

Tags: algebraic-complexity, arithmetic-circuits, probabilistic-computation

I was reading the lower bounds of arithmetic circuits. There in the proof of the theorem

> Over field $\mathbb{F}_q$, determinant, permanent requires depth-3 circuits of size  $2^{\Omega(n)} $  [Grigoriev, Karpinski, 1998]

They used a variant of the partial derivative matrix and used their rank to prove it. There they are randomly making a linear polynomial 0 then calculate the probability of that linear polynomial being 0 and finally proved it. [I started based on the idea I got from the proof. I may be wrong since I didn't understand the proof]

Again in the proof of the large rank of multilinear determinant and permanent of the partial derivative matrix, they are applying a random restriction on the variables to prove this.

What is the intuition behind this type of argument? Why it is even valid? Please help